# PHP DateTimeZone returns empty object

Tags: php

I'm trying to get DateTimeZone object, setting it the following way:

```
$dateTimeZoneRemote = new DateTimeZone('America/Edmonton');
```

However printing it out returns an empty object??

```
print_r( $dateTimeZoneRemote );
```

returns:

> `DateTimeZone Object ( )`

Running PHP 5.2.17

Comment: echo `$dateTimeZoneRemote`?

Comment: What version of PHP? I get `DateTimeZone Object
(
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => America/Edmonton
)` on 5.6.4

Comment: I don't think that it's empty. Whats return `print_r( $dateTimeZoneRemote->getName() );`?

Comment: @leggendario it returns 'America/Edmonton' ... hmm...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `print_r`/`var_dump`/`get_object_vars` don't show the properties of DateTimeZone as you expect. This [was a bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54567), [fixed](https://github.com/lonnylot/php-src/commit/e4b63c9e0418dd70fa3c1ad7ae43fad43aaa8bd8#diff-7b738accc3d60f74c259da18588ddc5dR2185) in PHP 5.5.

Whatever, using the methods that the class provide, you get the correct result in any version.

```
$dateTimeZoneRemote = new DateTimeZone('America/Edmonton'); 
echo $dateTimeZoneRemote->getName(); // print America/Edmonton
```

https://3v4l.org/Nv9Ct